# How to handle forms with variable number of inputs with node js

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express

I have a form on my page where one of the items input is a list of services available, and there are buttons to add and remove inputs for more or fewer services (i.e. enter first service click add service button and another service input spot appears, click remove service button and the last service input spot is removed)

Now I need a way to handle that input information on the back end using node.js and express of course without knowing ahead of time how many services are entered. I've read in other places about posting to an array but I don't know how that works with node.js/express.

Answer (score 1):

Get all the fields that can be added /removed via an array of values in the html form. On the server side, the array with be available under `req.body`.

**Note** - You will need body parser or something similar to get hold of the form inputs.

Also, if you are using ajax, serialize the form inputs before posting the form.

Comment: Is there a way I can post them as an array without using javascript?

Comment: normal form post works with arrays too. Ajax came in a lot later

Answer (score 0):

So for that would I just make the name properties of the inputs things like "service[0]" and "service[1]" and so on?